# Request dispatcher forward method not working in do post method on servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, forward, requestdispatcher

forward method in request dispatcher works fine when created in doGet() method in Servlet. But does not work when used in the dopost method. Also in Jsp file I have declared the method as doPost. Following is my code in servlet.

```
@WebServlet(name = "SignUpServlet")
public class SignUpServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("lk/ruh/uniAssist/spring/SpringXMLConfig.xml");
    SignUPService signUpservice = (SignUPService) ctx.getBean("signUpservice");


    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String studentName = request.getParameter("studentName");
    String regNo = request.getParameter("regNo");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
    String department = request.getParameter("department");
    String semester = request.getParameter("semester");

    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println(studentName);
    System.out.println(regNo);
    System.out.println(pwd);
    System.out.println(department);
    System.out.println(semester);

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("signup.jsp");

    requestDispatcher.include(request, response);




}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {




}
```

}

This the way it is in dopost method. nothing happens when it is in above format. But when I declare RequestDispatcher methods in doGet method it works fine. What is the reason behind this.

```
<div class="login-bottom">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form name="signUpForm" id="signup" method="post" action="/signUp">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="login-mail">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail">
            <input type="text" name="studentName" placeholder="Name with initials" required="">
            <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail">
            <input type="text" name="regNo" placeholder="RegNo (ex:2528)" required="">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required="">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail" placeholder="Department">
            Department
            <select name="department" id="depSelector" class="form-control1">
                <option>Civil and Environment Eng.</option>
                <option>Electrical and Information Eng.</option>
                <option>Mechanical and Manufacturing Eng.</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="login-mail" placeholder="Department">
            Semester
            <select name="semester" id="semSelector" class="form-control1">
                <option value="1">1 Semester</option>
                <option value="2">2 Semester</option>
                <option value="3">3 Semester</option>
                <option value="4">4 Semester</option>
                <option value="5">5 Semester</option>
                <option value="6">6 Semester</option>
                <option value="7">7 Semester</option>
                <option value="8">8 Semester</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 login-do" align="center">
        <img src="images/icon.png" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
        <label class="hvr-shutter-in-horizontal login-sub">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </label>
        <p>Already register</p>
        <a href="signin.jsp" class="hvr-shutter-in-horizontal">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is the relevant jsp code.

My whole web Xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<!--servlet declaration-->
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>TimeTableServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>lk.ruh.uniAssist.servlet.TimeTableServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>coursesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>lk.ruh.uniAssist.servlet.coursesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignInServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>lk.ruh.uniAssist.servlet.SignInServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignUpServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>lk.ruh.uniAssist.servlet.SignUpServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<!--Servlet Mapping-->

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TimeTableServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/timeTable</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>coursesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/courses</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignInServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/signIn</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignUpServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/signUp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**PS: It works fine when signup.jsp is used in the URL. But does not work with the mapped URL /signUp. That is the issue I am trying to resolve**

Comment: Looks like you're missing a lot of relevant code.

Comment: I'm surprised there are already 3 answers to this question.

Comment: You'll need to post your web.xml and your more of your servlet class (including the method signature). There is no way that anyone can give you an actual answer without these two crucial pieces of information.

Comment: @shinjw I have added all the files. So can anybody tell me the reason why I can't use URL /signUp to access the web page when above request dispatcher methods are declared in doPost method. How ever when I write request dispatcher commands in doGet it works fine. I need to know the difference between two methodologies. Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the solution. The reason behind this is because by default JSP calls Http Get method.

Comment: Yup with the full context. Its now painfully obvious

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in form tag method=post and and your servlet class your overriding method doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp).

Bydefault form tag method is get and your servlet class need to override method doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp).

If you will mis-match you will get R.E- HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL(ie-HTTP Status 405 Error)
P.S-Complete files.